# Can a request enter in two Nginx locations?

Tags: nginx

I have an Nginx config like this:

```
# match everything except /api/* and /redirected.html
location ~ ^/(?!api|redirected.html).* {
  if ($isFoobar = 1) {
    rewrite ^ /redirected.html redirect;
  }
}

# match everything except /api/*
location ~* ^/(?!api).* {
  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$server_name$1 permanent;
  }

  passenger_enabled on;
}
```

I would like any matching request to enter first in the location #1 and, if no rewrite is performed, enter in the second location.

So, the config should:

- Redirect anything but `/api/*` and `/redirected.html` to `/redirected.html` **if** `$isFoobar` is `1`
- Redirect anything but `/api/*` to `https` if is not already `https`

Is it possible with Nginx or do I need to repeat the rules of the location #2 in location #1?

Comment: These rules look very bad written... https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Comment: I simplified the config to focus the question on my problem, it's much more complex (unfortunately) and ifs can't be avoided. By the way, this has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: Could you describe in plain english what these locations should and should not match.

Comment: I added two comments to explain the regexps, I also added some more info.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution I found is to use nested locations:

```
# match everything except /api/*
location ~* ^/(?!api) {
  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$server_name$1 permanent;
  }

  passenger_enabled on;

  # match everything except /api/* and /redirected.html
  location ~ ^/(?!redirected.html) {
    if ($isFoobar = 1) {
      rewrite ^ /redirected.html redirect;
    }
  }
}
```

This way, both the rules are applied based on the current URL.